# How to disable TLSv1 on Microsoft Azure Application gateway

Tags: azure, ssl, load-balancing, tls1.2, azure-application-gateway

Application gateway is the load balancer in MS Azure which supports SSL certificate. In aws load balancer we select protocols which can be used to connect to the load balancer like TLSv1.1, TLSv1.2. 
In MS Azure can select the protocol the request should connect?
or Is there a method to disable TLSv1 from the Application gateway?

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Currently Microsoft Azure doesnot provide a feature to disable TLSv1.0 manually. So there is no method to disable TLSv1 from the application gateway.

Comment: It's possible !!

Comment: yes. It is possible now. If you check the answer. I have given the answer 7 years back.

Answer (score 7):

Now you can also disable TLS old version from Azure Portal,

1. Go to your Gateway > Listeners
2. Scroll down to end of your listeners
3. End of SSL Policy paragraph, there is a link, **change**
4. Click on the link **changed**,

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 3):

Yes, Now you can disable TLS 1.0 and 1.1 using Azure Application Gateway. Follow below link 
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/application-gateway/application-gateway-end-to-end-ssl-powershell